# Compilation privileges in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, oraclereports

I am using Oracle 11G and Oracle Developer 6i.

My problems are as follows:

- There are some tables in user1.
- I granted the select, insert, update, delete privileges to user2.
- I created respective synonyms for the user2.
- The user2 can use all the tables in already compiled oracle forms.
- In case of any modification in Oracle Forms/Reports, user2 cannot compile the form and it gives the following error:

`ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17069], [103930736], [], [], [], [], [], []`

What more priveleges are needed to be granted to user2 so that he may also modify the oracle forms/reports and then compile it.

Comment: i would be surprised if this was a permissions issue, you may need to report this to oracle support

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that something else is causing the problem. Can you check

- if you are using packages with definer rights (AUTHID definer)
- if you have dual table reference in code (change it to sys.dual)
- check privileges for all objects in code between two users. Its likely that user1 has some grants that user2 does not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "grant option"?

> grant select, insert, update, delete to user with grant option ;

ORA600 is a undefined and hard error in Oracle, if you have support with Oracle open an SR

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment from oracle about your error:

ORA-600:[17069] is an error signaled due to a failure to pin a library cache object--possibly the q$space.segwatch procedure. Perhaps this procedure is/was invalid at the time or was being recompiled during the execution of this job.

Regards.